# Coercive or not?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization

I had this problem in the exam.

Let $X = [x_1,...,x_d]^T$, $a\space \epsilon$ $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $C$$\epsilon$$\mathbb{R}$.

Argue for or against. $f(X) = a^TX + C||X||^2$ is coercive only for $C > 0$?

My answer: True.

Case $1$: If $C = 0$, then $f(x) = a^TX$. Linear functions are not coercive.

Case $2$ : If $C < 0$, then the function can go to $-\infty$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

If $C\ne 0$, then
$$
f(x)=C\left\|x-\tfrac{1}{2C}a\right\|^2-\frac{\|a\|^2}{2C}.
$$
Hence for $C>0$:
$$
f(x)=C\left\|x-\tfrac{1}{2C}a\right\|^2-\frac{\|a\|^2}{2C}\ge-\frac{\|a\|^2}{2C}
$$
while for $C<0$, $f(x)\to-\infty$, as $\|x\|\to\infty$.

Hence, $f$ coercive iff $C>0$.